# Is there a function to find the absolute root path in php?

Tags: php

for example:

/home/mydomain.co.uk/public_html/

Something generic for windows or linux?  Id like it to produce the root path only regardless of where i call the script from.  So not the absolute root path to my script.

Sorry is this is hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` will work on both

Comment: This is great thanks, is there a way of using a wild card for a directory? Because one of the folders i am using cant be determined.

So the path would be document_root/wild card/the rest of my path?

Comment: Umm no. You'd have to write a script to search through possible paths. You could get a list of paths and then use regex to match all with wildcards